# Is android Sqlite Concurrent transaction safe?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a single database connection, where i will be accessing this connection from multiple thread in parallel. I need to know that whether if i proceed with two or more insert/select transaction operation concurrently from two separate threads with same database connection.

> will there be any issue ?
>
> Is this the right way of doing ?

Can anyone correct me if am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The locks in sqlite apply to the whole database and not just individual tables or rows of table. With the increase in thread there will increase in transactions which would result in number of concurrency issues. If you looking for Database engine to handle lot transactions concurrently its better to shift to MySql or PostgreSQL.